# How to get a value inside modalbox based on the item that is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have several buttons on my page. for each button I want to open a modal box. However, inside the modalbox the data will be populated based on the button clicked. So I need a way to use the clicked items' value inside the modal box.

How can I do this?

Here is what I've tried.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(0)">Open w/ index 0</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(1)">Open w/ index 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(2)">Open w/ index 2</button>
```

JS

```
  $scope.open = function (index) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }, 
        index: function() {
          return index;
        }

      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

Modal HTML

```
<h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal! w/ index {{index}}</h3>
```

Here is a Plnk of a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/m65ATdiSdAUGxj69GgSV?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. You seem to already be sending items to the modal as you wanted. If you want `index` in the modal, add it to the end of the Args list for your modal controller and assign it (exactly the way you already do for `items`). If you want items specific to the index, specify them in the `resolve` function for `items`. Your example seems to be basically there for both of these already.

Comment: Maybe he means in the ModalInstanceCtrl ? You just use the same syntax as you would for a service dependency.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought was meant, but as I mentioned in my first point: if `index` is placed in the Arguments list for `ModalInstanceCtrl`, and basically used the exact way `items` is already used in the plunker example, it will work. Since `items` is already working this way, the question seems trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the index var which is passed using the resolve option, you'll have to add the var as an argument to the Controller of the Modal Window like this:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, index) {
```

you can use that var to define a $scope var, just like you did with the $scope.items.

```
$scope.items = items;
$scope.index = index;
```

This technique is described on the [Angular UI docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal):

> `resolve` - members that will be resolved and passed to the controller as locals;

Plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/6R8926rLxRzxDmVbNVsX?p=preview